# Composite Pattern and recursing through an XML document

Tags: c#, recursion, composite

I'm trying to use the composite pattern while recursing through an XML document.

The code I have so far is

```
public Composite TraverseNodes (XmlNodeList nodeList, Composite comp)
    {
       foreach(XmlNode in nodelist)
           if(xNode.Attributes != null)
             {
               Object x = getObjects(xNode) // getObjects returns an OO version of each node & their attributes;
               Composite child = new Composite(x);
               if(x != null)
               {
                   comp.Add(child);
                }
                if (xNode.HasChildNodes)
                {
                      TraverseNodes(xNode.ChildNodes, comp);
                 }
             }
        }
```

This will recurse through the XML document.  My problem is that I want the Composite to reflect the structure of the XML document, and at the moment it is only producing a flat list. So comp has 
        Comp
          Child
          Child
          Child

whereas what I want to achieve is something more like

```
    Comp
      Child
         GChild
         GChild
      Child
         GChild
         GChild  
            GGChild ...... and so on.....
```

I am using the code from this link to build my Composite class http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternComposite.aspx#_self2

Many thanks for any pointers.
Linda

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive call to `TraverseNodes` is passing `comp` where it should pass `child`.

Comment: Hi Av I thought I had tried that.  I'll give it another try.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes I did try that. The problem with that is that the child when passed doesn't retain any info about the parents. I really need to be able to pass comp.Add(child) to the recursive call I think.

Comment: The Composite pattern described in your link creates a tree that is navigable only from parent to children (and grandchildren, and so on). If you want references from children back to their parents, you'll need a more sophisticated structure.